# Checking to see if object has already been pushed into array Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, function

```
var cardNames= [];
```

This is my array I am pushing items
into it, but i need make it so you can only
 
push that same item into the array once.
 
How do i check the incoming item to see
if the item coming in is already in the array
, give an alert if it is?

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv that wont work with objects

Comment: @sam what type are the `items`?

Comment: If they are the same reference then it'll work with objects too. If not then OP should state so.

Comment: @sam Can you show what you are pushing into the array ? Is it an array of objects or simple array ?

Comment: Since you are new to the site (at least your account appears to be) I suggest that you try to be more thorough when asking questions, and include more than a single line of code. If you manage to be direct in your question while providing the most elements required for people to understand you'll get answers much more easily!

Comment: @Tuvia `Array.indexOf` absolutely will work with objects. Keep in mind objects with identical contents aren't equal; an object will only ever equal itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `indexOf` function:

```
if (cardNames.indexOf(newCard) !== -1) {
    console.log('The card has already been inserted!')
} else {
    cardNames.push(newCard);
}
```

If you are working with a collection you can easily check against a single property of the objects (they should have a unique key or an ID), for example using the `Array.some` or the `Array.find` functions.

```
if (cardNames.find( card => card.id === newCard.id ) ) {
    // Like before
} else {
    // push the new card
}
```

Edit: the docs are [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Edit 2: While `Array.find` works on newer browsers, [`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) has better backward compatibility.

Comment: That wont work with objects (that I know of)

Comment: No it doesn't, I just assumed that since the array is called `cardNames` it was an array of string. Editing the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you array contains the objects, you could use `Array.prototype.some` function

```
var arr = [{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }];

var result = arr.some(e => e.a == 1);

console.log(result); // true
```

Snippet

```js
var arr = [{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }];

var result = arr.some(e => e.a == 1);

document.write(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

**If** the items pushed are of string or number type then it is as trivial as checking `cardName.indexOf(item) !== -1`.

If you are checking if an object is in the array, then you *may* need to check via a loop and use some library to check equality (or use duck typing).